# Windows batch strip tags

Tags: batch-file

File with HTML Code:

```html
<table>
<tr><th>ID</th><th>NAME</th></tr>
<tr><th>1</th><th>Alex</th></tr>
<tr><th>2</th><th>Andy</th></tr></table>
```

How to OUTPUT DATA WITHOUT TAGS with windows .bat file? (no vb)

Like this:
1:Alex
2:Andy

Thanks

Comment: Why do you exclude vb? It's a scfript language which understands the xml format. Batch is not predestined for the task. Even if you remove the tags with a 3rd party tool like sed, `sed -e "s/<[^>]*>//g" test.xml` the output still contains `IDName`and the numbers in front of Alex and Andy` without a colon.

Comment: so, 3rd party is ok. I'll think about it.

Comment: consider using [xpath.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath.bat)  -> `xpath.bat html.xml //tr/th`

Comment: Whatever scripting tool you are using, share your attempts and describe what you have got trouble with! Otherwise this is not a question but a code request, which is off-topic here! Please read the [tour] and learn [ask]!

Comment: How this xpath can be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like batch, but honestly: it is not a suitable tool for processing xml files.
The following is more an exercise in logic and pain than a suitable solution (but works. At least with something like your example...):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (t.txt) do call :process "%%a"
goto :eof

:process
set "line=%~1"
set flag=0
set var=
for /l %%i in (0,1,100) do (
  if "!line:~%%i,1!"=="<" ( 
    set /a "flag+=1" 
    set "var=!var!:" 
  )
  if !flag!==0 set "var=!var!!line:~%%i,1!"
  if "!line:~%%i,1!"==">" set /a flag-=1
)
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%b in ("!var!") do echo %%b:%%c
```

How it works:
the first `for` loop processes each line of the textfile (one after the other).
The subroutine processes the line character by character. It increases the `flag` variable each time, it hits a `<` (plus add a `:`, because we know, the (possible) value is at it's end) and decreases at each `>`. So if `flag` is zero, we are "outside" of a tag, and can add the character to a variable.
The last `for` just reformats `var`, because there are too many `:` (every tag-start a `:` is added)

Comment: How can I ask more help from you? My skype is axxler

Comment: @Stephan Can you please add some comments on your code ! i found it very helpful in this situation Thank you !

Comment: @Hackoo: added a rough description (I know, you are able to read the code `;)`) (Note: the code is absolutely not optimized, it's just how it grew up. There are some traps and it surely will not work with every XML)